# PHP - Get value from saved dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, dropdown

I have a plugin in WordPress in which I can make custom field like dropdown etc. Now I need to get the saved value from the dropdown.

I have this:

```
$vt_city = get_post_meta($cs_job_id, 'cs_post_loc_city', true);
```

But that displays it meta instead of the value like this: not_filled

And what I need it to show is: Not filled

How can I achieve such thing?

Comment: which custom field plugin you are using?

Comment: It's a theme called "Jobcareer" it has jobs where I can add custom field to.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see nothing about it in the doc, but you can use a regex at least

```
$clean_meta = preg_replace("/^(\w{1})([a-z]*)_([a-z]*)$/","$1$2 $3",$vt_city);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do anything :(

Comment: Still got the same answer when I use: $vt_city = get_post_meta($cs_job_id, 'cs_post_loc_city', true);